# Can SharePoint 2007 and 2010 databases live in the same server without issues?

Tags: 2007

We are setting up a new SharePoint 2010 QA server and would like to use the same SQL server as our SharePoint 2007 QA server.  Are there any issues or gotchas with this strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work just fine. You don't need separate SQL instances either, just make sure you don't do the 'all in one, let the SharePoint installer sort everything out' install.

This is assuming that your SP2010 and SP2007 servers are 2 separate (virtual) servers talking to the same SQL database server.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if content deployment would be effected in this model?  Where QA 2007 deploys to prod 2007 and now I want to start creating 2010 DBs in the same SQL instance as QA 2007.

Comment: Yes, the front end and app servers are separate from the SQL host.

Comment: I don't anticipate any interference between the 2.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a problem as long as you use separate SQL instances for 2007 and 2010 on the same server. They will operate independent of each other so no problems should arise.

Comment: No need for 2 different SQL Instances. We host 10 SharePoint instances (2007 and 2010) on the same SQL Server Instance just fine.